# Mutiply the value from another tables include the same index using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
sourceindex | source | target | prob
    1       | apple  |   dog  | 2/(2+2+1)
    2       | dog    |   cat  | 2/(2+2+1)
    3       | door   |   cat  | 1/(2+2+1)
    2       | dog    |   apple| 2/(2+2+1)  
    4       | cat    |   dog  | 2/(2+2+1)  -----step 1  table1

sourceindex | source | target | prob
    1       | apple  |   dog  | 2/(2+2+1)
    2       | dog    |   cat  | 4/(2+2+1)
    3       | door   |   cat  | 1/(2+2+1)  
    4       | cat    |   dog  | 2/(2+2+1)  -----step 2  sum the prob group by sourceindex
                                                        and output to new table 



---------------------------------------------

 sourceindex    | source | target | prob      | result  
        1       | apple  |   dog  | 2/(2+2+1) | (2/(2+2+1))*(2/(2+2+1))
        2       | dog    |   cat  | 2/(2+2+1) | (2/(2+2+1))*(4/(2+2+1))
        3       | door   |   cat  | 1/(2+2+1) | (1/(2+2+1))*(1/(2+2+1))
        2       | dog    |   apple| 2/(2+2+1) | (2/(2+2+1))*(4/(2+2+1))
        4       | cat    |   dog  | 2/(2+2+1) | (2/(2+2+1))*(2/(2+2+1))
```

**step3 return the result value which is prob multiply with table2 prob column depend on same sourceindex and insert to table1**

Comment: I just don't understand the problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the expected outcome?

```
| SOURCEINDEX | SOURCE | TARGET | T1_PROB | STEP3 |
|-------------|--------|--------|---------|-------|
|           1 |  apple |    dog |   0.400 | 0.160 |
|           2 |    dog |    cat |   0.400 | 0.160 |
|           3 |   door |    cat |   0.200 | 0.040 |
|           2 |    dog |  apple |   0.400 | 0.160 |
|           4 |    cat |    dog |   0.400 | 0.160 |
```

That is based on this query:

```
select
        t1.sourceindex
      , t1.source
      , t1.target
      , format(t1.prob,3)          as t1_prob
      , format(t1.prob*t1.prob,3)  as step3
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.sourceindex = t2.sourceindex
;
```

and this assumed data, not I have reduced prob from a string into the numeric result of the indicated calculations.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`sourceindex` int, `source` varchar(5), `target` varchar(5), `prob` decimal(12,3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`sourceindex`, `source`, `target`, `prob`)
VALUES
    (1, 'apple', 'dog', 0.400),
    (2, 'dog', 'cat', 0.400),
    (3, 'door', 'cat', 0.200),
    (2, 'dog', 'apple', 0.400),
    (4, 'cat', 'dog', 0.400)
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`sourceindex` int, `source` varchar(5), `target` varchar(3), `prob` decimal(12,3))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`sourceindex`, `source`, `target`, `prob`)
VALUES
    (1, 'apple', 'dog', 0.400),
    (2, 'dog', 'cat', 0.800),
    (3, 'door', 'cat', 0.200),
    (4, 'cat', 'dog', 0.400)
;
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80d14/1 where you can try it or amend it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, you need to perform a left join in order to consider all records from table_1 and compute the value of a new field as the product of the two probes:

```
SELECT t1.sourceindex, (t1.prob * t2.prob) as result from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.sourceindex=t2.sourceindex
```